# jqGrid - Editable: true not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am driving mad with this..

Even after reading the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules) from jqGrid, having using this grid before (with success), now I am not able to edit the cell.

I even commented a big part of the code leaving it with the following lines:

```
function initGridProjectDetail(options) {
    $("#" + options.table).jqGrid({
        url: options.dataUrl,
        colModel: [
            {name: 'CategoryName', label: 'Kategorie', editable: true }
        ],
        jsonReader: { id: 'Id' }
    });
}
```

What can be the reason for not be able to edit this cell? Thanks for the help.

**Note**: the grid is rendered, has content and even the sorting is working. The only thing missing is the "editable" functionality.

Comment: Please post your inlineNav method. Also make sure navGrid method is called before.   http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav

Comment: I am using the example: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#example and there they do not use inlineNav method. Shouldn't this work without it?

Comment: You should decide which [editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#editing) you want to use: cell editing, inline editing or form editing. There are different options of integration the chosen editing mode in the grid. How you want that user activate editing of cell or row: click/double-click on cell/row, selection of the row and clicking on the button from the toolbar (`navGrid` or `inlineNav`methods) or on inline button (`formatter: "actions"`) and so on. In case of cell editing you need use `cellEdit: true` option.

Comment: No it wont work without inlineNav, assuming that you prefer inline edit

Comment: @Dryadwoods: Why you remove from the posted code all editing related parts (calls of `editRow` for example)? If you created some code based on [the example](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#example) you should post *your modified code* here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should just use `jQuery(this)` instead of `jQuery("#" + options.table)`. You can use `$(this)` or `jQuery(this)` inside of every callback. You should verify additionally that you defined variable `lastsel2`.

Answer (score 0):

Totally my fault on this one.

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
            if (id && id !== lastsel2) {
                jQuery("#" + options.table).restoreRow(lastsel2);
                jQuery("#" + options.table).editRow(id, true);
                lastsel2 = id;
            }
        },
```

With copy paste from the example source I left the wrong table Id.
I appreciate Oleg's last comment, because it made me look into this. Please write an answer to accept it as the solution.

Comment: Please *append the text of your question* if you post additional information about the question. You should write your own answer only if you solved the problem yourself and want share it with other. You posted one more time too few code. Where you defined `lastsel2` and `options` and so on? By the way you should better use `jQuery(this)` instead of `jQuery("#" + options.table)`.

Comment: Oleg, Please add a new answer to this question and write whatever you want in there, my problem is solved just like I said (because of your comment) and since I can not choose a comment as a valid answer, then please do as I said. Then I will choose it as the accepted answer.